# Issue creating a materialized view in redshift using the python connector

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use the python module: redshift_connector to create a materialized view in a postgresql redshift database.  My query is akin to:

`query = """CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW some_results AS SELECT * FROM other_results;"""`

I pass this into the function below and nothing happens, however if I log into the database via terminal and run the same commands it works.  Is this a permissions thing, or is there something wrong with my connector code?  I can read from tables in the database with the connector without an issue.

````
def redshift_query(query)
     conn = redshift_connector.connect(
     host=XXXX,
     port=5439,
     database=XXXX,
     user=XXXX, 
     password=XXXX)
     print('Connected to Redshift...')
     with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        print('Querying Database...')
        t1 = time.time()
        cursor.execute(query)
        t2 = time.time()
        print(f'command sent, this took {t2-t1}s')
    pass```
````

Comment: Have you tried committing?

Comment: conn.autocommit = True appears to have done the trick!